# Grails Jasper hidden parameter

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, ireport

I am creating a basic report wherein I could pass the domain model passed by the controller to the view and use that instance as a parameter for the report.

Here the part of the `<g:jasperReport>` in the view[.gsp]

> Note: ${user} is an instance of User inside the domain classes having those string properties: lastName, firstName, middleName

```
<g:jasperReport 
  jasper="reportByUser"
  format="pdf, html">
    <input type="hidden" name="u_lastName" value="${user.lastName}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="u_firstName" value="${user.firstName}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="u_middleName" value="${user.middleName}" />
</g:jasperReport>
```

Here the part of the xml code inside the `reportByUser.jrxml`

```
<parameter name="user_lastName" class="java.lang.String" />
<parameter name="user_firstName" class="java.lang.String" />
<parameter name="user_middleName" class="java.lang.String" />
```

The problem is when I run the report on the grails, either format return a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
<g:jasperReport 
  jasper="reportByUser"
  format="pdf, html">
    <input type="hidden" name="u_lastName" value="${user.lastName}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="u_firstName" value="${user.firstName}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="u_middleName" value="${user.middleName}" />
</g:jasperReport>
```

You are passing: name="**u**_lastName"

But in the jasper file is specting: name="**user**_lastName"

Check it...